# Cannot solve symbol "RAND"

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);


    final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.things_array);
    n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)];
            tv.setText(nextValue);
        }
    });
}
```

At the values[RAND, RAND is red and says it cannot be solved?

How can I fix this?

Matthew

logcat:

08-13 21:41:48.302    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-13 21:41:48.351    9865-9865/com.MR.brd V/ActivityThread﹕ Class path: /data/app/com.MR.brd-1.apk, JNI path: /data/data/com.MR.brd/lib
08-13 21:41:48.566    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 4% free 8339K/8643K, paused 51ms, total 65ms
08-13 21:41:48.641    9865-9865/com.MR.brd I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 16.150MB for 8294416-byte allocation
08-13 21:41:48.716    9865-9872/com.MR.brd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 16438K/16775K, paused 75ms, total 75ms
08-13 21:41:48.813    9865-9870/com.MR.brd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 16438K/16775K, paused 15ms+1ms, total 97ms
08-13 21:41:48.948    9865-9865/com.MR.brd I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms
08-13 21:41:48.954    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so
08-13 21:41:48.978    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so
08-13 21:41:48.982    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
08-13 21:41:49.170    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/MMUMapper﹕ fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
08-13 21:41:49.176    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-13 21:41:49.436    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/MMUMapper﹕ fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
08-13 21:41:55.045    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/VelocityTracker﹕ Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
08-13 21:41:55.045    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/VelocityTracker﹕ tpd read x fail: Bad file number
08-13 21:41:55.045    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/VelocityTracker﹕ tpd read y fail: Bad file number
08-13 21:41:55.116    9865-9865/com.MR.brd V/Provider/Setting﹕ invalidate [system]: current 2613 != cached 0
08-13 21:41:55.119    9865-9865/com.MR.brd V/Provider/Setting﹕ from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
08-13 21:41:55.242    9865-9865/com.MR.brd W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f050001 a=-1 r=0x7f050001}
08-13 21:41:55.314    9865-9865/com.MR.brd I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms
08-13 21:41:55.341    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/MMUMapper﹕ fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
08-13 21:41:55.507    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/MMUMapper﹕ fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
08-13 21:41:55.547    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/MMUMapper﹕ invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52d7d000) size(1536000)
08-13 21:41:55.547    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/MMUMapper﹕ invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x53264000) size(1536000)
08-13 21:41:55.560    9865-9865/com.MR.brd I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms
08-13 21:41:59.563    9865-9865/com.MR.brd V/Provider/Setting﹕ from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
08-13 21:41:59.563    9865-9865/com.MR.brd W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
08-13 21:41:59.564    9865-9865/com.MR.brd D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-13 21:41:59.564    9865-9865/com.MR.brd W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410458a8)
08-13 21:41:59.576    9865-9865/com.MR.brd E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3856)
            at com.MR.brd.MyActivity2$1.onClick(MyActivity2.java:48)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 21:42:01.384    9865-9865/com.MR.brd I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 9865 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this :

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(values.length);
```

See that : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm

**EDIT :**

```
ArrayList<Integer> alReadyGet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        int nextValue = r.nextInt(values.length);
        for (int i =0; i < alReadyGet.size(); i++) {
            if (alReadyGet.get(i) == nextValue) {
                nextValue = r.nextInt(values.length);
            }
        }
        alReadyGet.add(nextValue);
        tv.setText(values[nextValue]);
});
```

I think it will work :) Tell me :p

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Have one more question.. how can i make it so that the values from the array don't repeat?

Comment: You can create an ArrayList<Integer>  and put inside values of nextInt.
Then before get nextValue, you can test if your value is on your ArrayList.
It is not opti but it work. I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: I'll try this.. Waiting for the better solution :)

Comment: [See this](http://www.technonutty.com/2013/10/how-to-generate-unique-random-numbers-java-android.html) I think it is the unique solution.

Comment: I tried them both but can't seem to get it to work.. Could you post the code and tell me where to put it?

Comment: Sorry for the noob question.. where do i put it in my code?

Comment: Instead of your onClickListener, after final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.things_array);

Comment: Not working, once i start the app the textview shows some funny number and when i click the button it crashes

Comment: Can you post LogCat plz ?
I forgot to add nextValue in ArrayList ! Fixed

Comment: Done, added it to the original post

Comment: Oh yeah ! I tried to setText with an id (values) but it is not an id, it is the index on values[]. So get String into values[nextValue] :) Fixed. I should work

Comment: The funny number is still present, but after i click the button the text from the array apears. But it still repeats the text?

Comment: Text will not repeat. For the funny number i don't know. You can iniate your TextView befoire to set your listener.

Answer (score 2):

You missed to define RAND

`Random RAND=new Random();`

Comment: THIS ANSWER APLIES ASWEL!